Register ASP.NET Core endpoint programatically at startup
I want to do something that seems like it should be easy, but I've been googling for hours and not found a way to do it.
I have a controller something like this:
public class MyController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("/SomeRoute")]
    [HttpPost("/Someroute")]
    public JsonResult MyEndpointFunction() {...}
}

However, instead of decorating this function with [HttpGet] /[HttpPost], I want to have a function that would allow the consumer of my package to specify something besides /SomeRoute or even not register it at all without it defaulting to anything.  And actually, the not registering it at all is the main goal.
I thought I had found a solution using [FeatureGate], but if a feature is disabled, that will cause it to return a 404.  My intent is to allow the consumer of the package to override with their own implementation.
I thought about making MyEndpointFunction virtual so they could override it that way, but that would automatic endpoint mapping would still see the base class.  And if I make that class abstract, then the consumer would have to implement it to get the default behavior which is not what I want.
What I'm looking for is something like this:
public static WebApplicationBuilder UseMyEndpointFunction(this WebApplicationBuilder builder, string route)
{
    // TODO how to do this?
    return builder;
}


You can use a dynamic route and perform the mapping to a controller/page dynamically.This can be achieved using MapDynamicControllerRoute and MapDynamicPageRoute
SubDomainRouteTransformer.cs:
public override async ValueTask<RouteValueDictionary> TransformAsync(HttpContext httpContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
{
    var controllerName = values["controller"] as string;
    if (controllerName == "Test") {
        values["custom"] = "aa";  
    }
    
    return values;
    
}

config in Program.cs
builder.Services.TryAddTransient<SubDomainRouteTransformer>();

CustomShortCircuit.cs
public static class CustomShortCircuit
{
    public static WebApplication MuteRoute(this WebApplication app)
    {
        app.MapDynamicControllerRoute<SubDomainRouteTransformer>("{custom=SomeRoute}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        app.MapShortCircuit(404, "SomeRoute11","bb");
        return app;
    }
}

The result are:


